# Insert text and Numbers in bash script Menu prompt

Tags: bash, loops, insert

I am trying to create a script where the user would run it select an option and then be prompted to enter a `$FileName` and a `$Number` how would I do this in bash?

Here is what I have right now I need help in option [1] and [3]:

```
Begin
echo "-----------------------------"
echo "   Data Processing Menu      "
echo "-----------------------------"
begin case structure
echo "What would you like to do"
echo "*[1]Enter Number $Number of Files $FileName to output.txt*"
echo "*[2]Show Classifiers only"
echo "*[3]Auto All $All of Files $AllFileName to output.txt*"
echo "*[4]Exit/Abort*"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo -n "Enter your choice [1-4]:"
read Pmenu
case $Pmenu in
 1) "Building";;
 2) cut -f 4 input.txt;;
 3) "Building";;
 4) exit 0;;

 esac
```

Here is the data that this script is processing through (`input.txt`):

```
FilePath    Filename    Probability ClassifierID    HectorFileType  LibmagicFileType
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 02a3f29050abd76f8d5dbe5972dff932    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 068e56e175dc41a91ab0a34b4729200d    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 07812135184347a9a2c772665e14d5b2    10  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

thank you for your help

Comment: You say: `I'm not sure how to word this`.  I say: `I'm not sure how to read this`.

Comment: sorry, Im just trying to make a prompt where the user could type a $number and $filename on a field in that menu and then have it process those choices to an output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash's [select](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select) command to simplify the menu:

```
echo "-----------------------------"
echo "   Data Processing Menu      "
echo "-----------------------------"

choices=(
    "Enter Number $Number of Files $FileName to output.txt"
    "Show Classifiers only"
    "Auto All $All of Files $AllFileName to output.txt"
    "Exit/Abort"
)
PS3="Enter your choice: "

select Pmenu in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $Pmenu in
        1) "Building"; break ;;
        2) cut -f 4 input.txt; break ;;
        3) "Building"; break ;;
        4) exit 0;;
    esac
done
```

I'm not clear on what help you need for 1 and 3.